# Laravel 5 - How to make a relationship between 3 tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I have 3 tables in my database with the following structure:

```
'projects'
-> id
-> name

'tasklists'
-> id
-> project_id

'tasks'
-> id
-> project_id
-> tasklist_id
```

I made for each table a model.

```
- Project.php
- Tasklist.php
- Task.php
```

My goal is to print in my view each tasklist with all the tasks for a specific project.

So as an example:

```
Project name: Stackoverflow
-> Tasklist #1
   -> Task #1
   -> Task #2
   -> Task #3
-> Tasklist #2
   -> Task #4
   -> Task #5
-> Tasklist #3
   -> Task #6
```

I have a little bit of knowledge about the simple relationships in Laravel between two tables. But I can't figure out how to make use of the relationships with 3 tables.

Can someone give me some tips/hints? Which relationship type is the best to use? How do I write this out and in which model should I place this? I know the logic inside my head but I don't know how to write it out in code.

---

**Edit -> This is what I have now.**

Tasklist

```
public function projects()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
  }

  public function tasks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'tasklist_id');
  }
```

Task.php

```
public function tasks()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tasklists');
      }
```

Project model

```
public function Tasklists()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      'App\Task',
      'App\Tasklists',
      'project_id', 
      'tasklist_id',
      'id',
      'id'
    );
  }
```

Now when I print dd(Project::first()->tasklists);

I get all the tasks from my database (not sorted on project_id or tasklist_id).
So I guess I'm closer but not there yet.

Kinds regards,

Dylan

Comment: `task` only needs to be related with `tasklist`, since `tasklist` already contains the relation with the `project`. Relating `task` with `project` directly is redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I also though about that. That's overkill. Can you also help me out a little bit further?

Comment: I don't know much about Laravel, I could help you with MySQL directly, if that's what you are using.

Comment: You will have to create many to many relationhips and then access data using hasManyThrough method.
Project has many takslists (many to many or 1->many)
Takslist has many tasks    (many to many ot  1-many depends on your requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for hasManyThrough -- You should be able to use your existing relationships like this ...

Project.php ...

```
function taskLists(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\TaskList');
}
```

TaskList.php

```
function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks');
}
```

And then in your controller ...

```
Projects::with('taskLists', 'taskLists.tasks')->get();
```

That will return all of the projects with the task lists as a relationship.  Then on the lists, the tasks as a relationship to those.

To print, you can do something like ...

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <h1>Project Name: {{$project->name}}</h1>
    @foreach($project->taskLists as $list)
        <h4>{{$list->name}}</h4>
        <ul>
            @foreach($list->tasks as $task)
                <li>{{$task->name)</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: How the Schema will look like for such relationship?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Many to Many Relationship**
To do so you will create 3 tables:

1. projects
2. tasks
3. project_task (this is pivot table which holds information about relations)

To learn more about it read this official document https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Hi, if I look at the documentation, the function which looks the closest to what I should use is 'Has Many Through' (I guess?). But I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Tasklists belong to Projects, Projects have many tasklists.

Tasks belong to Tasklists, Tasklists have many tasks.

Projects have many tasks through tasklists.

These descriptions should line up with what Laravel calls the relationship methods.

Comment: This is the logic behind it. Yes. But can you explain it to from A - Z with some example code (or, even better: an example with my own structure). I'm very new to Laravel.

Comment: Have you read the laravel docs?  The way I wrote these should make it very easy to convert to code...

Comment: Yes. I did. I have made some changes to my code. I'll update the main post.

Comment: You really don't need project_id on the tasks table, but if you do, then you can do a hasMany directly from the Project model.  (Projects have many tasks).  However, this is redundant with the tasklist relationship.

Comment: I understand that project_id isn't required on tasks, will remove that. Yes, I need to make a relationship between Tasklists and Tasks first. I've now updated the code above. Can you help me further out from here? Thanks.

Comment: Tasklists isn't has many through, Tasks are has many through.  I think you need to read my answer closer.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what I did wrong. I'm reading your first comment over and over but can't figure it out. Maybe because my interpretation is wrong. Can you tell me a litte bit more in depth - what I need to change?